# How does one return a reference pair from a newly inserted pair (to a map)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, std, stdmap, std-pair

How do I correctly and efficiently return a pair from a newly inserted pair to a map?

```
inline pair<unsigned int, T> *createObj(unsigned int UID){
    static pair<unsigned int, T> ret;

    objList.insert(pair<unsigned int, T>(UID, T()));

    if (UID_Counter <= UID) 
        UID_Counter = UID+1; 
    ret = make_pair(UID, objList.find(UID)->second);
    return &ret;
}
```

The above returns a object to use, but whatever I change in **ret** does not change in the "real pair" in the map...

Basically what i want to achieve is:

1. Insert new **object Z** into **map A**
2. ("Child"-class) Change the stuff in the returned **object Z**
3. In every update cycle, iterate through the objects in **map A** and use the actual data loaded into **object** "A-**Z**" when updating...

Comment: Your requirements are very unclear. When you insert into a map you obtain (through a bit of indirection) a reference to the inserted object, so that's no problem. Can you describe your goals a bit more clearly?

Comment: My goals are simply to return a **pair<x1, t2>** reference to the newly inserted **map<x1, t2>**

Comment: I see. I think Luc sorted you out already. Do read the manual for `std::map` carefully, its interface involves lots of pairs in unusual places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular overload of `insert` that you're using returns an `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. In particular the first member of that pair is an iterator to either the element that was newly inserted or the element that was already present. Thus:

```
pair<const unsigned int, T>&
createObj(unsigned int UID)
{
    auto inserted = objList.insert(pair<unsigned int, T>(UID, T()));

    if (UID_Counter <= UID) 
        UID_Counter = UID+1; 

    return *inserted.first;
}
```

Notice that I'm returning a reference where you were returning a pointer and that the key type is `const unsigned int`, not `unsigned int`. You can use `map_type::value_type`, too (where `map_type` is the type of your container).

If you're wondering why your code wasn't working, it's because you were storing a copy of the mapped object inside `ret`, so any modification through the pointer you returned would only affect that copy.

Comment: Thanks! Basically I foresaw the issue with returning "ret" instead of an actual element of the map... but now I have something to work with. :)

Comment: What's the point of the conditional? `UID` is a local variable that has no effect.

Comment: However, for some reason I get `illegal indirection` pointing at `*inserted.first`, using your code sample...

Comment: @Alexander: Do you have C++11? Otherwise you can't say `auto`, but have to spell out the type.

Comment: @kerrek-sb, UID is not a local variable, it is a parameter of the function.

Comment: @Alexander: ... which *is* a local variable! You're not passing it by reference anyway.

Comment: In that sense it's true what you're saying, it's local. But it's value is being sent to the function from elsewhere... Should maybe have excluded it and its use for clarity, sorry for that. 

Regarding C++11, I'm not using it, but I have spelled out the type `pair<const unsigned int, T>`.

Comment: @Alex: no, the type is what Luc said, `std::pair<iterator, bool>`, where `iterator` is the iterator type of your map. Please please do read the manual (or even [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)) for `std::map`, it really does have a quite unique interface that has some surprises.